# OWL - combining unionOf and allValuesFrom

Tags: semantic-web, owl

Is it correct to write an `owl:unionOf` as follows:

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Camera">
      <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collections">
        <owl:Class>
          <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
              <owl>onProperty rdf:resource="#hasType"/>
              <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Digital"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
          </rdfs:subClassOf>
        </owl:Class>
        <owl:Class>
          <rdfs:subClassOf>
            <owl:Restriction>
              <owl>onProperty rdf:resource="#hasType"/>
              <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Film"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
          </rdfs:subClassOf>
        </owl:Class>
      </owl:unionOf>
</owl:Class>
```

Is there any other way to specify that the ***hasType*** property should have values either ***Digital*** or ***Film***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you have is correct. Using a union operator creates an anonymous class that contains elements from both. So it would look something like

```xml
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Camera">
            <rdfs:subClassOf>
               <owl:Class>
                   <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                       <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasType"/>
                            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Digital"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasType"/>
                            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Film"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                    </owl:unionOf>
                </owl:Class>
            </rdfs:subClassOf>
    </owl:Class>
```

or

```xml
 <owl:Class rdf:ID="Camera">
                   <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                           <owl:Restriction>
                                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasType"/>
                                <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Digital"/>
                            </owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:Restriction>
                                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasType"/>
                                <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Film"/>
                            </owl:Restriction>
                    </owl:unionOf>
  </owl:Class>
```

I recommend using an ontology editor like Protege to ensure that your syntax is correct though.

Comment: So isn't it necessary that the contents of **unionOf** should be classes? Is it correct if the union operator is used directly inside the class _Camera_ , without using the tags **<rdfs:subClassOf>** and **<owl:Class>**

Comment: The union operator is used on classes, Property restrictions are anonymous classes as well. As for the other tags, based on the OWL language reference it looks like you should be able to use it without them. Just be sure validate your ontology before using it in an application.

Comment: Just a note, yes you can use the unionOf tag without the other tags, answer amended to reflect this. This is semantically equivalent to stating that the class camera is equivalent to the union.